# Download files from fileshare

Tags: inno-setup, file-sharing

I'm creating a inno installer/updater. Now I need a way to download my files from a fileshare. I found already some solutions for downloading over ftp/http but non over a smb file share. Is it possible to download/copy a file from a smb file share using inno setup? And how to do it if it is possible?

Comment: "smb file share" is just a normal network path (UNC path), right? So you do not have to download anything. Just install the files from there. Or do you need to authenticate to the share?

Comment: No authentication needs to be happen on the fileshare.